# Google Maps JS API v2 - Simple Multiple Marker Example

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm fairly new to gmaps and Im using v2 because of the search function that I didnt find in v3.

I've got an array of data that I want to loop through and put the markers on the map =)

It seems really easy but I cant get it to work with v2 at all...

Here is my what my array format and code looks like:

```
function createMarkers(myLatLng,html) {
  var marker = new GMarker(myLatLng, markerOptions);
  GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
  });
  return marker;
}


var locations = [
  ["Bondi Beach",-33.890542,151.274856],
  ["Coogee Beach",-33.923036,151.259052],
  ["Cronulla Beach",-34.028249,151.157507],
  ["Manly Beach",-33.80010128657071,151.28747820854187],
  ["Maroubra Beach",-33.950198,151.259302]
];


for (var i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
   var locations = locations[i];
   var myLatLng = new GLatLng(locations[1],locations[2]);
   var dynamicmarker = createMarkers(myLatLng);
   map.addOverlay(dynamicmarker);
}
```

The beachnames got position locations[0], the lat got position location[1] and lng got position location[2] and so on...

I didnt use the names of the beaches as the "html"option, but I only get one marker on the screen. Ive checked the for loop and it looks correct, v3 is so simple to get it to work. But I need to have the search function that v2 has...

Would be so grateful if someone could give me a tip or show me how to go thru the array and get those markers to show up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a few problems in the for loop. First of all `location.length` should be `locations.length`. Then you seem to be re-declaring a `locations` variable within the for loop. Remember that JavaScript does not have block scope.

You may want to try the following:

```
var i, myLatLng;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
   myLatLng = new GLatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
   map.addOverlay(createMarkers(myLatLng));
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! Daniel I dont know how much I could thank you right now! :D It worked like a charm!

I really need to check my spelling to when Im writing for loops, Im so used to mark the var names and then all var names that are the same are marked in Zend Studio but this didnt show up like it does in php...

Daniel, again, thank you so much!!!